# What is 'pay their way through legal battles'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading an article and could not undertand the line marked in bold.

Crruption in high places is a malaise that is easy to diagnose but difficult to cure. Even in the rare cases they are arraigned before a court, top politicians often **pay their way through legal battles**, and spend little or no time in incarceration.

Please help.
Article reference :
http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/The-conviction-and-after/article17302631.ece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simple means that the accused politicians have enough money to hire really  good lawyers who battle the charge in court. Truth is supposed to prevail in court, but often is about who has the best lawyers or lawyer team.